# How to create a color code for points based on 3rd dimension with ListPlot or ListLogLogPlot

Tags: plotting

I have seen some similar posts but could not quite find what I am looking for.

I would like to create a 2D plot with discrete points that are color coded by a 3rd dimension value. The color function I am trying for is a rainbow color scheme that changes linearly between the smallest and largest values of the 3rd dimension. This would be similar to what ListPointPlot3D seems to do  automatically if you specify a color function, but with a 2D plot.  Here is the example of the output of the ListPointPlot3D color coded based on the z dimension:

[image: example 3D with correct color function coloring]

From the code

```
ListPointPlot3D[data, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",PlotRangePadding -> None, BaseStyle -> {14, Bold}]
```

The example data can be found here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6mvpo1kiw5b1t2o/example_points_color_coding.csv?dl=0

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

This example is not for geographic data, but it seems like this kind of function would also be very useful for geographic data, so I am surprised there is no built-in version for points on a 2D plot in Mathematica (although I could have missed it!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lpp3d = ListPointPlot3D[data, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

Rescale the last column of `data`, then style each pair of first two coordinates with `ColorData["Rainbow"]` evaluated at the rescaled value of the third column.

```
data2 = data;
data2[[All, 3]] = Rescale[data2[[All, 3]]];
ListPlot[Style[#[[;; 2]], ColorData["Rainbow"][#[[3]]]] & /@ data2, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Alternatively, if the surface does not bend on itself, post-process the output of `ListPointPlot3D` to remove the third coordinates of `Point` primitives:

```
Graphics[Replace[lpp3d[[1]], Point[x_] :> Point[x[[;; 2]]], {0, Infinity}], 
   AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Great!  Thanks so much!  The first solution works well for me.  It doesn't appear to work with ListLogLogPlot unfortunately, but it works to plot the log of the data and re-label the axes.  :)